# Why is clearInterval() function is not stopping the javascript timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a basic pomodoro clock, I am stuck right at the beginning, the timer does not stop reaching 0, where is the problem with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var targetTime, intervalID;
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        targetTime = Date.now() + (1 * 60 * 1000);
        intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000, targetTime, intervalID);
    });
    // timer callback for setInterval function
    function timer(targetTime, intervalID) {
        var secondsLeft = Math.ceil((targetTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
        $('h1').text(secondsLeft);
        if (secondsLeft <= 0)
            clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Pomodoro Clock</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1></h1>
      <button>start</button>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `targetTime, intervalID` as a global instead of passing it

Try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var targetTime, intervalID;
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    targetTime = Date.now() + (1 * 60 * 1000);
    intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  });
  // timer callback for setInterval function
  function timer() {
    var secondsLeft = Math.ceil((targetTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
    $('h1').text(secondsLeft);
    if (secondsLeft <= 0)
      clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pomodoro Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <button>start</button>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the right strategy. @segmentationfaulter I'd suggest adding the following line of code before you call `setInterval`, otherwise multiple clicks to the button before the timer runs out will cause a runaway interval: `if (intervalID) clearInterval(intervalID);`

Answer (score 1):

You have intervalID a parameter, which is setting it to 'undefined' in your timer function, remove it and it works fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var targetTime, intervalID;
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    targetTime = Date.now() + (1 * 60 * 1000);
    intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  });
  // timer callback for setInterval function
  function timer() {
    var secondsLeft = Math.ceil((targetTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
    $('h1').text(secondsLeft);
    if (secondsLeft <= 0)
      clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pomodoro Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <button>start</button>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```